# End to end delay over N link including the (simplified) propagation delay

Tags: switch, ip, tcp, networking, switching

It is well know ([see this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51970/end-to-end-delay)) and easily verifiable that end-to-end delay in case of trasmission of P packets of size L over N equal links (same transmission rate R) with zero propagation delay is given by the formula

```
N*L/R + (P-1)*L/R
```

I'd like to know how change this formula if we add propagation delay in the hypothesis that all the links are of the same distance D and speed C.

In my convinction the propagation delay does not affect the transfert delay, and every link add a propagation delay of D/C so the formula should be:

```
 N*L/R + (P-1)*L/R + N * D/C
```

I looked for confirmation in the literature but couldn't find any source on how to add the (simplified) propagation delay, so I'm asking here.

This is not an home work: I'm looking for a more complete formula. The base formula already use simplified assumptions, so why not add the propagation delay too ?

Comment: Why don't you just ask yourself what is happening in slow motion? You are also making assumptions that all forwarding is store-and-forward which is not always the case.

Comment: thanks @Zac67 for your reply but I cannot understand your hint

Comment: Which one? Just picture each single bit leaving the source, traveling the length of the cable and being received on the other end.

Comment: @Zac67 I end up concluding that the propagation delays sum to N * D/C
Isn't it correct ?

Comment: If *C* refers to media-adjusted speed of light (c0*VF), then yes. Trivially, *v=d/t* means *t=d/v* with *d* =N*D.